# How to get the file associated with a graphics device?

Tags: r

While printing a plot to a file, I want to find the location of the file that I'm printing to.

```
pdf("test.pdf")
plot(1:5)
# Somehow retrieve "test.pdf"
dev.off()
```

In this example, I specified the filename when I called `pdf` so the answer is obvious.  My use case is when the file location has been automatically generated, for example in a knitr document.

For file connections, you can get the associated file using `summary(conn)$description`.  I was hoping to be able to get something useful from `summary(dev.cur())` or `str(dev.cur())`, but no luck there.

How can I go from `dev.cur()` to the associated file?  Alternatively, how can I retrieve the location of the file that the plot is being written to?

Comment: Don't think you can. `showConnections` doesn't give any hint. Wonder how the connection is handled internally. Guess you have to find a way to keep track of the name with which `pdf` is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to contradict myself and what I said in the comments. The `.Devices` object provides the needed info:

```
pdf()
.Devices
#[[1]]
#[1] "null device"
#[[2]]
#[1] "pdf"
#attr(,"filepath")
#[1] "Rplots.pdf"
#[[3]]
#[1] ""
```

The file name is stored as an attribute, as you can see from the output.

As @RichieCotton noticed, the "singular" version of the above object, `.Device`, gives info on just the current device (and not on the entire list), so extracting the filepath is as easy as:

```
attr(.Device, "filepath")
#[1] "Rplots.pdf"
```

Comment: Fantastic.  `attr(.Devices[[dev.cur()]], "filepath")` is what I need.

Comment: Actually, it's even easier than that. `attr(.Device, "filepath")`.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added your comments in the answer.